# Can’t access Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I can’t access sites in the Stack Exchange network like serverfault.com, stackoverflow.com, and superuser.com from my home network.  I can access these sites from my mobile so I wondered whether my home network has been blocked or where the problem lies.

A few details:

- I’m in the UK, using Vodafone as my broadband provider.
- I can access all other websites
- I’ve reset my router, cleared browser caches etc.
  -`curl -v  https://stackoverflow.com` results in `connect to 151.101.1.69 port 443 failed: Operation timed out`
- In Safari I get the message "Safari can’t connect to the server stackoverflow.com";
- In Chrome I get "This site can’t be reached, stackoverflow.com took too long to respond."
- Results of traceroot are below and it seems they have some kind of loop in them...

```
~ » traceroute stackoverflow.com
traceroute: Warning: stackoverflow.com has multiple addresses; using 151.101.1.69
traceroute to stackoverflow.com (151.101.1.69), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  vodafone (192.168.1.1)  1.668 ms  0.581 ms  0.491 ms
 2  host-212-158-250-37.dslgb.com (212.158.250.37)  7.259 ms  19.635 ms  13.128 ms
 3  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  7.306 ms  7.392 ms  6.866 ms
 4  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  7.641 ms  7.573 ms  7.746 ms
 5  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  8.470 ms  8.215 ms  8.289 ms
 6  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  8.521 ms  8.148 ms  8.189 ms
 7  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  9.048 ms  8.366 ms  8.345 ms
 8  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  9.425 ms  9.376 ms  9.445 ms
 9  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  9.339 ms  9.167 ms  9.224 ms
10  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  9.448 ms  9.675 ms  9.467 ms
11  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  10.439 ms  10.670 ms  10.247 ms
12  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  10.549 ms  10.135 ms  10.767 ms
13  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  10.494 ms  10.346 ms  10.330 ms
14  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  11.427 ms  11.547 ms  11.210 ms
15  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  11.354 ms  11.142 ms  11.103 ms
16  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  11.576 ms  12.854 ms  11.383 ms
17  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  12.239 ms  12.720 ms  13.312 ms
18  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  12.146 ms  11.910 ms  11.722 ms
19  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  13.395 ms  12.968 ms  12.668 ms
20  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  13.733 ms  12.972 ms  13.272 ms
21  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  16.941 ms  13.357 ms  13.052 ms
22  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  13.371 ms  13.460 ms  13.191 ms
23  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  13.799 ms  13.901 ms  13.951 ms
24  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  14.054 ms  14.404 ms  14.371 ms
25  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  14.586 ms  14.882 ms  14.307 ms
26  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  15.415 ms  15.377 ms  15.336 ms
27  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  15.152 ms  15.942 ms  15.223 ms
28  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  15.163 ms  15.673 ms  15.269 ms
29  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  16.590 ms  16.114 ms  16.245 ms
30  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  16.543 ms  16.195 ms  16.856 ms
31  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  17.852 ms  16.318 ms  16.170 ms
32  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  17.303 ms  17.145 ms  17.052 ms
33  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  17.497 ms  17.803 ms  17.000 ms
34  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  17.512 ms  17.510 ms  17.622 ms
35  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  18.825 ms  21.375 ms  18.701 ms
36  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  18.298 ms  18.221 ms  17.848 ms
37  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  18.686 ms  18.030 ms  17.785 ms
38  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  18.699 ms  19.150 ms  19.540 ms
39  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  19.072 ms  19.252 ms  19.439 ms
40  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  19.522 ms  19.629 ms  20.092 ms
41  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  19.575 ms  20.232 ms  19.858 ms
42  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  20.250 ms  20.512 ms  20.070 ms
43  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  20.335 ms  20.687 ms  20.445 ms
44  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  20.894 ms  21.854 ms  20.949 ms
45  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  20.891 ms  21.005 ms  21.161 ms
46  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  21.460 ms  21.678 ms  21.503 ms
47  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  22.510 ms  22.280 ms  22.516 ms
48  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  22.981 ms  22.086 ms  22.181 ms
49  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  22.434 ms  21.935 ms  26.773 ms
50  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  24.376 ms  23.351 ms  23.687 ms
51  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  23.387 ms  24.313 ms  23.093 ms
52  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  23.378 ms  23.131 ms  23.225 ms
53  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  24.230 ms  24.515 ms  24.019 ms
54  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  24.011 ms  23.840 ms  24.230 ms
55  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  25.702 ms  24.272 ms  24.623 ms
56  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  25.145 ms  24.894 ms  25.304 ms
57  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  25.540 ms  25.505 ms  24.868 ms
58  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  25.266 ms  25.858 ms  25.809 ms
59  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  26.330 ms  25.696 ms  25.819 ms
60  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  27.084 ms  26.012 ms  25.778 ms
61  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  26.466 ms  27.021 ms  26.327 ms
62  63.130.105.130 (63.130.105.130)  26.934 ms  28.824 ms  27.513 ms
63  63.130.104.194 (63.130.104.194)  26.939 ms  28.848 ms  26.925 ms
64  10.200.18.37 (10.200.18.37)  27.459 ms  29.027 ms  27.037 ms
```

Comment: That looks like a routing table has gone belly up. After you leave your network the route goes to a 10. address. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Really strange. Is it definitely outside my home network? If so I could call my Internet Service Provider. But what I don’t get is why other people aren’t experiencing the issue...

Comment: @AdamGriffiths the other users are not so lucky:)